# enabling full screen mode in youtube video

Tags: youtube, google-app-maker

When I embed a youtube video in a Google Appmaker app, fullscreen mode is disabled

[image: full screen is unavailable]

Is there any way that this can be enabled? I have tried adding the allowFullScreen tag (see below) to the iframe tag but that doesn't seem to make any difference:

```js
function getIframeHtml(url) {
   return '<div class="wrapper full-size"><iframe src="' +
          app.sanitizer.sanitizeUrl(url || '') +
          '" frameborder="0" allowFullScreen="allowFullScreen" class="full-size"></iframe></div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be infeasible, since it is not explicitly allowed by App Script:
[image: html]
[image: console]